# installing python package in sagemaker sparkmagic pyspark notebook

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr, amazon-sagemaker

I want to install new libraries in a running kernel (not bootstrapping). I'm able to create a sagemaker notebook, which is connected to a EMR cluster, but installing package is a headache.
Unable to install packages on notebook. I've tried several methods like installing packages via terminal in jupyterLab.

```
$ conda install numba
```

The installation seems to be working fine on conda_pytorch_p36 notebook, but the packages are not installed on SparkMagic (pyspark) notebook.

Error code:

```
An error was encountered:
No module named numba
Traceback (most recent call last):
ImportError: No module named numba
```

The jupyter magic command also doesn't work only in pyspark notebook

```
!pip install keras
```

Error:

```
An error was encountered:
invalid syntax (<stdin>, line 1)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    !pip install keras
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Based on answer in a [github](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/52) post, neither did this work

```
from subprocess import call
call("pip install dm-sonnet".split(" "))
```

Comment: Could you check try [1] by using the command like 
    sc.install_pypi_package("keras")
[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-managed-notebooks-scoped-libraries.html

Comment: also conda command has typo, could you check again? conda install numpy

Answer (score 4):

when you are running `$ conda install numba` via the terminal in JupyterLab,
it's actually succeeding the installation on your local environment. The thing is, when you are using Sparkmagic as your kernal, the code in the cells are always running on the spark cluster, not on the local notebook environment. To run the content of a cell locally you should write `%%local` in the beginning of the cell. After that everything in that cell will run locally and the installed module will be available. 
Otherwise you should install the module on the remote spark cluster. 
Read more here: 
https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/sparkmagic/blob/master/examples/Pyspark%20Kernel.ipynb